# This snippet of code does not stop stoi from running when it gets bad input

Tags: c++

I am stuck with this bit of code. I am trying to get this code snippet to restart if the user input isn't numeric. It doesn't seem to do this and I don't know why. I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hand. Sorry about the start and end line indents, it's driving me mad.

```
void write() {
  string x, y;    
  int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, no = 0;

  /*highNumber (x1, y1);*/

  cout << endl << " x to display: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << endl << " y to display: ";
  cin >> y;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    if (x[i] >= '0' || x[i] <= '9') {
      no++;
    }
  }

  if (no == x.length()) {
    no = 0;
  }
  else {
    write();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    if (y[i] >= '0' || y[i] <= '9') {
      no++;
    }
  }

  if (no == x.length()) {
    no = 0;
  }
  else {
    write();
  }

  x1 = stoi(x);
  y1 = stoi(y);

  highNumber (x1, y1);
}
```

Comment: Don't recurse, use a loop. Recursing doesn't "restart" - it suspends, calls the function, and then continues after the call returns, like every function call does.

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what's stumping you? Be specific.

Comment: Isn't an `invalid_argument` exception thrown when it doesn't succeed?

Comment: Use `strtol` which cleanly reports non-numeric inputs via an output parameter.

Comment: See also [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), which tests a character if it is a numeric digit.

Comment: Thanks to moldbnilo. I will fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake seems to be right here: `if (x[i] >= '0' || x[i] <= '9')`
This should probably be `if (x[i] >= '0' && x[i] <= '9')` if I understand your code correctly, even though I am having some difficulty parsing it. Either way, the code you have there before will return true for all characters. This checks that it is within the number range of ascii characters.

Also, seems like your second loop is checking `x.size()` instead of `y.size()` when working on `y`. This should matter if `x` doesn't have the same size as `y`.